# Azure Function disabled setting "user" field to HTTP request object on the 26th of April 2022

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

(!) Issue cannot be reproduced locally.
Azure Function Version ~4
Node Version 14.18.1

Creating a simple HTTP triggered Azure Function and setting just two simple properties we get the following code:

```js
module.exports = async function (context, req) {

    req.auth = {authField: 'some value'}
    req.user = {userField: 'some value'}
    context.log(`${JSON.stringify(req,null,2)}`);

    context.res = {
        body: 'responseMessage'
    };
}
```

The logger prints the following object:

```json
{
  "method": "POST",
  "url": "xxx",
  "originalUrl": "xxx",
  "headers": {
    /// ...
  },
  "query": {},
  "params": {},
  "body": { "name": "Azure" },
  "rawBody": "{\"name\":\"Azure\"}",
  "auth": { "authField": "some value" }
}
```

As you see only `auth` is set and not `user`.
The same failing behavior can be seen in version `4.2.0`.

When I test with Azure Function ~3 the output looks like this:

```json
{
  "method": "POST",
  "url": "xxx",
  "originalUrl": "xxx",
  "headers": {
    // ...
  },
  "query": {},
  "params": {},
  "body": { "name": "Azure" },
  "rawBody": "{\"name\":\"Azure\"}",
  "auth": { "authField": "some value" },
  "user": { "userField": "some value" }
}
```

As you see the field is set.
The following custom v4 `4.1.0-17156` also sets the `user` field.

The field `user` was used by us through the [express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) (v6.1.0) which is [using](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt/blob/v6.1.0/lib/index.js#L33) it when no value is provided for `requestProperty`.

I could not yet reproduce it but in out transpiled from Typescript project, we get the following runtime error:

```
FailureException: Cannot set property user of [object Object] which has only a getterStack: TypeError: Cannot set property user of [object Object] which has only a getterat Object.run
```

The issue started at the beginning of the day of 26th of April 2022.

Questions:

- what is the reason?
- is a quick roll back to the functioning Azure Function custom version possible?

Comment: Prabably your DTO does not have a setter, so you can put a getter for that property, and it should work, but would need more details to be sure

Comment: @EduG unfortunately there is no more information. It was a hard investigation. Our prod services went down without even a deployment one after another. `request` object belongs to Azure Function host domain, it is not a good idea to change it. We learned it the hard way. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the culprit in [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-nodejs-worker/pull/483/files) PR, which was added for Azure Function runtime v4.2.0.

The user field was added with only a getter.
We took the code and made the minimal example:

```
class Request {
    #cachedUser?: string | null;
    constructor() {
    }
    get user(): string | null {
        if (this.#cachedUser === undefined) {
            this.#cachedUser = "some value";
        }
        return this.#cachedUser;
    }
}
```

and got the following transpilied version:

```js
var __classPrivateFieldGet =
    (this && this.__classPrivateFieldGet) ||
    function (receiver, state, kind, f) {
        if (kind === 'a' && !f) throw new TypeError('Private accessor was defined without a getter')
        if (typeof state === 'function' ? receiver !== state || !f : !state.has(receiver))
            throw new TypeError('Cannot read private member from an object whose class did not declare it')
        return kind === 'm' ? f : kind === 'a' ? f.call(receiver) : f ? f.value : state.get(receiver)
    }
var __classPrivateFieldSet =
    (this && this.__classPrivateFieldSet) ||
    function (receiver, state, value, kind, f) {
        if (kind === 'm') throw new TypeError('Private method is not writable')
        if (kind === 'a' && !f) throw new TypeError('Private accessor was defined without a setter')
        if (typeof state === 'function' ? receiver !== state || !f : !state.has(receiver))
            throw new TypeError('Cannot write private member to an object whose class did not declare it')
        return kind === 'a' ? f.call(receiver, value) : f ? (f.value = value) : state.set(receiver, value), value
    }
var _Request_cachedUser
class Request {
    constructor() {
        _Request_cachedUser.set(this, void 0)
    }
    get user() {
        if (__classPrivateFieldGet(this, _Request_cachedUser, 'f') === undefined) {
            __classPrivateFieldSet(this, _Request_cachedUser, 'some value', 'f')
        }
        return __classPrivateFieldGet(this, _Request_cachedUser, 'f')
    }
}
_Request_cachedUser = new WeakMap()

// this section is added for testing
const request = new Request()
request.user = 'new value'
console.log(JSON.stringify(request.user))
```

So, it always returns the the initial value, which in our example is "some value" but in the original code is simply `undefined` and does not allow to set it.

Comment: i got exactly same issue in nodejs azure functions due to this PR change

Comment: @Brian Pham, if the question helped you somehow, would you mind also upvoting the question?:)

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Hours wasted trying to figure this out. Thank you for confirming this.

Comment: @EddieB if you think the question is valuable can you upvote it as well?

Comment: It is already done